Spring boot 3.2.4 Unsupported class file major version 65
I am building a project with Java 21, Gradle and Spring Boot 3.2.4 and only for the test (classes) phase I get: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65 or Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo. or also Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/provider/LocaleDataProvider. while for the building phase all is fine. How is it possible?
in Gradle (version 8.7) I have set up as follow:
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    toolchain {languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)}
}

What is wrong?

Are you sure you're building it with Java 21? What is your JAVA_HOME set to? What do you get when you type java -version at a prompt?

@DavidConrad i get: openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.2.13.1 (build 21.0.2+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.2.13.1 (build 21.0.2+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Why the issue is only with test classes?

"Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/provider/LocaleDataProvider." means that whatever is doing this instrumenting doesn't support class version 65 (Java 21). You may need to upgrade something (e.g. a library or maybe a Gradle plugin) so it supports Java 21. You may want to inspect to full exception stacktrace to see if you can identify exactly what is doing this. Usually this is ASM or another bytecode manipulation library that is causing the problem.

In any case, without a [mre] and a full exception stacktrace, this is not conclusively answerable.

And it happens with the tests, because apparently something in your tests is using an outdated bytecode manipulation library, and not in your main code.

This type of issue only arises when the jdk- version is not compatible with the spring version, you can thoroughly check the version of jdk, your program is picking, make sure it is between jdk-17 to jdk 22

No, this error usually happens when a bytecode manipulation library doesn't support a newer version of Java. You're thinking of an UnsupportedClassVersionError thrown by the JVM, but in this case it is an IllegalArgumentException with a similar message. And even if it had been an UnsupportedClassVersionError, you cannot conclusively say it's thrown by the JVM without inspecting its stacktrace.
